# How could I make this code change the text box size based on user input, and make the default size 3?

Tags: javascript, html

First Name:

```
<script language = "javascript">

  function sizeChange(x){
    var len = 3;
    if (document.x.value.length > 3 && document.x.value != "")
    {len =  document.x.value.length
    alert(len)}
    else {alert(len)}
    }
</script>
```

```js
 function sizeChange(x){
        var len = 3;
        if (document.x.value.length > 3 && document.x.value != "")
        {len =  document.x.value.length
        alert(len)}
        else {alert(len)}
        }
```

```html
 First Name: <input  type="text" name="firstNa"  size = "sizeChange("firstNa")">
```

How could I make this code change the text box size based on user input, and make the default size 3? The function doesn't seem to be called, and it returns a null value when I insert a test warning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this

```js
  function change_size(){
       let input = document.getElementById("firstNa").value;
       document.getElementById("firstNa").size = input.length;
    }
```

```html
First Name: <input  type="text" id="firstNa"  size = "3" oninput="change_size()">
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use "oninput" :

```js
var renderNewSize = function(){
  var el = document.getElementById('firstName');
  el.size = el.value.length;
}
```

```html
First Name: <input  type="text" name="firstNa"  size="3" oninput="renderNewSize()" id="firstName">
```

Comment: you can find the documentation in here.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Attribute/oninput